# Webscraping with div ng scope class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to scrape the Event History Table on this site (for example) https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/parceldetail/2004001003

However, the class of this "table" is ng-scope and none of the tutorial I googled mentioned how to tackle this class. Can someone provide me some guidance on how to scrape this into a dataframe?

My problem is when I run this it returns nothing

```
table1 = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "panel-body"})
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem you're having? It's just a class name, doesn't affect scraping in any way.

Comment: I edited; sorry I don't have much experience in doing this

Comment: Ok, so your problem isn't with ng-scope class but with the fact that this site is written in Angular. You need to load it, let Javascript run, then things will be accessible to you. Or figure out where the data is really loaded from, probably via Ajax/fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML element "panel-body" is empty because the JavaScript has not loaded the API response when your scraper requests the page.

Rather than scraping the page, you can query the API directly.  I found the API endpoint by inspecting the page and viewing the GET requests when the page loaded.

```
import requests

# GET request to API
url = 'https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/api/parcel_assessmenthistory?ain=2004001003'

# request url content
r = requests.get(url)

# read JSON from response
data = r.json()

# print first element of JSON
print(data['Parcel_AssessmentHistory'][0])
```

Output:

```
{'TaxYear': '2023', 'BillNumber': '', 'BillType': '', 'BillTypeDesc': '', 'BillStatusCode': '', 'BillStatusCodeDesc': '', 'OwnershipCode1': '3', 'OwnershipCode1Desc': 'Review Not Required', 'OwnershipCode2': '7', 'OwnershipCode2Desc': 'Non-Reappraisable', 'DocumentType': 'B', 'DocumentTypeDesc': 'File Correction                                             ', 'DocumentReasonCode': 'U', 'DocumentReasonDesc': 'Non-reappraisable Trust Transfer (SEC. 62D)', 'DateCreated': '', 'DateToAuditor': '', 'RecordingDate': '05/29/2009', 'SequenceNumber': '50', 'DocumentNumber': '0798640', 'PercentInterest': '00%-0', 'LandValue': '697735', 'ImpValue': '295271', 'LandReasonCode': 'T', 'LandReasonCodeDesc': 'Change in Ownership (Transfer)', 'ImpReasonCode': 'T', 'ImpReasonCodeDesc': 'Change in Ownership (Transfer)', 'LandBaseYear': '2006', 'ImpBaseYear': '2006', 'LandValuationDate': '09/06/2005', 'ImpValuationDate': '09/06/2005', 'LandAppraisalDate': '10/31/2005', 'ImpAppraisalDate': '10/31/2005', 'LandAddedValue': '', 'ImpAddedValue': '', 'NewConstructionDate': '', 'NewConstructionType': '', 'NewConstructionTypeDesc': '', 'FixtureValue': '', 'PersonalPropertyValue': '', 'HomeOwnerExemption': '0', 'RealEstateExemption': '', 'FixtureExemption': '', 'PersonalPropertyExemption': '', 'TaxOriginCode': '', 'TaxOriginCodeDesc': '', 'TaxReasonCode': '', 'TaxReasonCodeDesc': '', 'TaxRateArea': '00016', 'ProcessingCode': '', 'ProcessingCodeDesc': '', 'CPI': '', 'PSEGYear': '2023', 'ExemptionKey': ' ', 'ExemptionStatus': 'None'}
```

Inspect page for API endpoint URLs:

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks so much! Just a quick question, this gets the Assessment History table, but how about the Events History table?

Comment: I guess I have to change the url but I don't know where to get that for the events history table

Comment: The parcel details are here: https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/api/parceldetail?ain=2004001003 You could loop through ain values and append them to the ain=number to get all of the parcels. The parcel owner history is here: https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/api/parcel_ownershiphistory?ain=2004001003

Comment: May I ask how do you get these links? Also, this has details about the parcel but not about the Events History table from the original link. Is there a way to get that too since it is the thing I want to scrape?

Comment: I added an image with the location of the endpoints. You can find what you need there.

Comment: Anytime, happy to help!

Comment: just a side question: do you know how scaleable this code is? Would it work if I loop through like a million parcel?

Comment: yes, you could definitely do that. I would add some error handling, try/except or something and you could output the data to a CSV, JSON, whatever. It might be worth adding a sleep() between calls in case they throttle or cut you off.